# How to remove material shadow from ToggleButton?

Tags: android, material-design

Today I've faced a problem:

In my custom layout there are LinearLayout with grey background and ToggleButton right after TextView inside this LinearLayout. 
Toggle button have transparent background. 
But in android Lollipop here are unnecessary shadow.
I've tried elevation=0dp attribute. But this did't fixed my problem.

This happens when I'm set api = 21

[image]

And happens this on older apis < 21

[image]

Here is the sample layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/grey_light">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0123" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How to remove this shadow?

Comment: @JoanColmenero you can check my code using api 21 and see same results

Comment: @Dahnark
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:translationZ="0dp"
        android:translationX="0dp"
        android:translationY="0dp"
nothing helps

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try to use `style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless`

Change the widget to appcompat (or whatever you are using).

I am using this:

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

Answer (score 4):

ToggleButton manages its elevation and translationZ with included state list animator. You can disable it by setting:

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

or by providing your own selector to handle these values:

```
android:stateListAnimator="@drawable/my_selector"
```